# recursion in asm program

Tags: assembly, recursion, x86, fibonacci, gnu-assembler

I've a question about asm (x86 / GAS) program that returns a segmentation-fault.
It's about Fibonacci : I think that the algorith is ok : (pseudo-code)

```
fibo(int number){
    if (n < 2)
        return number;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
```

I don't understand why there is an error. 
A C program calls the asm function.

Here is the code :

```
fibo:
    movl    4(%esp), %ebx    #argument n in %ebx
    cmpl    $2, %ebx          # test: is n < 2 ?
    jnl     recur            # no, recursion

    jmp     quit             # yes : quit

recur:


    movl    %ebx, %eax  # get value of argument n
    subl    $1, %eax     # n-1
    pushl   %eax        # push n-1
    call    fibo        # recursive call : fib(n-1)
    movl    %eax, %edx  # save result in  %edx
    movl    %ebx, %eax  # get value of argument n
    subl    $2, %eax     # n-2
    pushl   %eax        # push n-2
    call    fibo        # recursive call : fib(-2)
    addl    %edx, %eax  # add fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Can you help me to find where is segfault ?

thanks !

PS: here is the ret :

```
quit:   movl    %ecx, %eax  #result in %ecx
        ret
```

Comment: Hang on, you wrote this code, but you aren't able to step through it in a debugger to locate the problem?

Comment: You don't seem to be setting up the stack frame for the function correctly -- I don't see `ebp` being adjusted anywhere...

Comment: Heck, what was the input that caused that?  That particular recursive implementation is going to be very hard on the stack.

Comment: I'am new to asm and I don't use debugger yet @Oli Charlesworth

Comment: @lilawood: If you're going to be doing any programming (especially assembler), you really really need to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @Oli, I use gdb (in C programming) but I didn't know it can be used to debug asm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How to you return from your function?
2. Do you expect your `call` to preserve the values in registers?

The answers will get you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you don't show your ret instruction, which is important. Also, you save the intermediate result of add in edx. That's not going to work - the recursive call that follows is also going to do that and will clobber the value you had at this call level. You'll need to store that intermediate value on stack as well.

Comment: I've stored the intermediate value but I don't understand why I should use %ebp whereas I already use %esp : to duplicate the stack ? thanks

Comment: There is no requirement for you to set up an explicit stack frame using ebp. You can use esp, as you do - it's a bit more error prone during development, that's all.